# Does Cognito Forms display ads on forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am looking for an alternative to Adobe FormsCentral. I mostly use FormsCentral for job applications (embedded in my website).

Does Cognito Forms display ads when applicants are filling out/viewing the application online?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito Forms does not show ads for embedded forms, but does show a Powered by Cognito Forms link at the bottom for forms accessed directly from Cognito Forms.  This is very important to educate the user that Cognito Forms is a tool being used to collect information on behalf of another organization, not necessarily the company responsible for the information being collected.

We currently include a similar message on our email confirmations, for similar reasons.  We plan to support removing this message on all of our paid plans (starting at $10 per month) as we feel comfortable not showing this message for emails as long as an organization is paying us.  Even this small amount of money is enough to deter most evildoers that might try to leverage Cognito Forms for phishing scams and other abusive uses.